# Getting error The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it wpf, How to use Dispatch.invovef

Tags: wpf

I am trying to catch bitmap image and display in bitmapsource I used conversion methos as follows

```
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

private BitmapSource Bitmap2BitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    BitmapImage retval;

    try
    {
        retval = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                     bitmap.GetHbitMap(),
                     IntPtr.Zero,
                     Int32Rect.Empty,
                     BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
    finally
    {
        DeleteObject(hBitmap)
    }

    return retval;
}
```

and code to display image is follows

```
Bitmap bmp= (Bitmap)e.frame.clone();
imgPic.source= imageconversion(bmp);
```

I have google it for this error...I come to know about dispatch.invoke method. Please suggest me how to use in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dispatcher can be invoked with a new instance of `System.Threading.ThreadStart` which gets a lambda expression containing the code you want to be executed on the UI thread. Make sure to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` and not `Dispatcher.Current` as the latter doesn't necessarily return the UI thread.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Input, 
    new ThreadStart(() => 
    { 
        // Do something 
    }));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to yoru answer.

Comment: Thanks for solution. But I did not get Thredstart...Is it necessary in namespace???